# "Tener un objeto consigo" vs "Llevar un objeto encima"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, modismos

¿Cuál de las dos construcciones es más idiomática y por qué?

> *Tener* un objeto *consigo*
>   *Llevar* un objeto *encima*

La pregunta es simple, pero es importante los recursos que se den para sustentar cualquiera de los dos. Estoy muy interesado en la respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se emplea bastante "consigo mismo" para evidenciar una acción que recae sobre el propio sujeto ("Se enfadó consigo mismo.") pero el pronombre personal "consigo" se usa relativamente poco en relación con llevar objetos, quizás porque es idéntico al presente del verbo "conseguir" (aunque por el contexto esto sería improbable, esto explicaría que  "conmigo", que no puede tener otro significado, se use bastante más). Pero depende sobre todo de lo implícito que quede el pronombre personal en la frase y el contexto. Ejemplos:

Si al pagar una cuenta en un bar le digo a mi amigo que "*llevo la cartera*" queda implícito que la llevo conmigo, metida en algún bolsillo. Es una aclaración innecesaria.

En cambio, si llamo por el móvil y digo que "*estoy en las escaleras y traigo una lavadora*" no es evidente si acompaño a dos operarios que llevan el pesado trasto y hablo en sentido figurado (la traen los operarios, no yo), o si la llevo realmente yo sobre mis espaldas.  Añadir "*conmigo*" en este caso es muy importe para que se capte el motivo de las llamada (¡que necesitas ayuda urgente!).

Por otra parte, "encima" (de "en"+"cima" ="sobre la montaña") es un adverbio de lugar, que está sobre algo o alguien, de modo  que lo que tienes "encima" es siempre algo que tienes "contigo", pero lo contrario muchas veces no será cierto:

*Llevo conmigo un abrigo porque lo llevo puesto encima (**sobre** los hombros) y también llevo zapatos conmigo, pero  los llevo puestos debajo (no encima) en los pies. Y llevo a mi novia conmigo, pero tampoco la llevo encima. Pero mi jefe nunca está conmigo[1] y siempre lo tengo encima[2].*

[1] en el sentido de "*nunca está de acuerdo conmigo*".

[2] en el sentido de "*siempre está vigilándome*".

Answer (score 1):

Primero, lo correcto es ***un objeto***, por concordancia de género. Pero ***una cosa*** es más idiomático y es femenino (Die Sache, Das Ding).

Segundo, depende de la región en la que uno se encuentre. Tanto ***llevar una cosa consigo*** como ***llevar una cosa encima*** son correctos e idiomáticos; pero la primera forma es más común en España y la segunda en América en mi experiencia.

Comment: No mencionaste *tener* algo consigo. Hay alguna diferencia?

Comment: Para mí es un uso sinónimo. *Tener algo* es el equivalente de *etwas haben*.

Comment: Si eso ya lo sabía, en alemán se tiene *etwas haben* para los dos. No es el caso en español donde se ven varias alternativas por ello la pregunta.

Comment: Lo que vés aquí es la diferencia entre el caso de número determinado y el indeterminado. Me explico, cuando dices, por ejemplo, **una cosa**, sabes que existe un objeto (y solo uno pues es singular). Cuando dices **algo** no sabes si existe o no y no es necesariamente un objeto, pero sabes que es solo uno pues es singular. En el uso cotidiano, **tener algo** se usa no solo para objetos sino para estados existenciales concretos o subjetivos, por ejemplo una enfermedad o un estado emocional.

Comment: Sí, es cierto. Pero estamos divergiendo del tema, pues esto se desvía de la pregunta. :)

Comment: No estoy tan seguro de que sea una divergencia mayor. :-) En las ocasiones en que he hecho traducción, he encontrado que hacerse este tipo de planteamientos semióticos ayudan mucho a transmitir la intención original del autor.

Comment: Cierto, cierto. Digamos que estamos de acuerdo en nuestro desacuerdo. :-)

Answer (score 1):

El contexto es importante. Alguien puede llevar un objeto consigo, pero no necesariamente encima. Por ejemplo:

> Él lleva un amigo *consigo* y una chaqueta *encima*.

*Encima* denota ubicación; mientras que *consigo*, no.

Comment: "Llevar un amigo consigo"? No estoy seguro esa frase sea oportuna dado que aquí hablamos de objetos. Encima denota ubicación, sí. Pero consigo también de manera general. No has respondido la pregunta respecto a cuál sería considerado más correcto. En términos generales ¿cuál de los dos es más idiomático? ¿porqué?

Answer (score 1):

Donde yo vivo, se usan igualmente, solamente dependiendo de si es un contexto formal o informal. Por ejemplo, para decirle a tu jefe que llevas el móvil pero está en silencio, se diría:

> Llevo el móvil conmigo a todas partes, pero cuando trabajo lo tengo en silencio.

Mientras que para decirle a un amigo que puede llamarte cuando quiera, porque llevas el móvil, diría:

> Siempre llevo el móvil encima, ¡puedes llamarme cuando quieras!

Aún así, se suele usar siempre *llevar encima*. Por lo menos aquí en Cataluña cuando hablamos en español tendemos a usar *llevar encima* porque en catalán no hay un equivalente común de *llevar conmigo* (llevar encima sería *portar a sobre*, mientras que llevar conmigo sería algo como *portar amb mi* y esto no se suele usar).

Supongo que es algo que depende tanto del contexto, de la formalidad que se requiera y del lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

> Llevar un perro consigo.
>
> Tener un perro encima.

Pueden ser muy diferentes en dependencia del contexto y eso es más importante que cuán idiomáticas son... (son bastante parecidas, aunque llevar encima puede que sea más común, en fin, determina el contexto en un sentido más fino).
Las demas respuestas están bien, solo que por ahora no puedo hacer comentarios.